# On doing "npm install" it shows "Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...FFso8TBG3jS7\nYdtExKk'"

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, npm

So, I am trying to do some TensorFLow via the official guide (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflowjs-nodejs-codelab/#2). I have dowloaded the package.json and the webpack.config.js.

pacakage.json is as follows:

```
    {
  "name": "tfjs-examples-baseball-node",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "description": "Deep learning models for classifying baseball metrics",
  "scripts": {
    "start-client": "webpack && webpack-dev-server",
    "start-server": "node server.js"
  },
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "clang-format": "~1.2.3",
    "mkdirp": "~0.5.1",
    "webpack": "~4.28.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~3.4.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^1.3.2",
    "argparse": "^1.0.10",
    "socket.io": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

webpack.congig.js looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './client.js',
    output: {path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), filename: 'bundle.js'},
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        noInfo: true,
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        disableHostCheck: true
    }
};
```

When I run the "npm install". It installs some of the stuff but not everything and gives the following error:

```
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated 
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated 
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...FFso8TBG3jS7\nYdtExKk'
```

I have tried `npm cache clear --force` but it still doesn't work. I tried `npm install -g` which apparently installs all dependencies but only mkdirp from the dev-dependencies leaving all the others uninstalled.

Can someone suggest something to try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you are on windows OS, try

1. Delete npm-cache in C:\Users{{your-username}}\AppData\Roaming\
2. Then run `npm cache verify`
3. run `npm install`

Answer (score 1):

For Mac os users,

1. first run "npm cache clean --force"
2. then run "npm i"

Answer (score 0):

when your `cmd` not `run as administrator` it is not able to clear the cache.
I also have this issue with `npm install`, I solved my issue with below instruction and I hope it solve your issue also.

1. run the bash or Command Prompt with `run as administrator`.
2. run the `npm cache clear --force` for clearing the cache.
3. run `npm install`.

[image]